# Member 'XmlSchema' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could anyone explain what is the error below ? I am new in asp.net coding.

This problem happen while I create a devExpress Report Class file.
Is it because the file consists

```
this.dataSet1.DataSetName = "DataSet";
this.dataSet1.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
```

---

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member 'XmlSchema' was not found.

*the error is on line 51.

```
**Line 51:         string strSchema = ((string)(info.GetValue("XmlSchema", typeof(string))));**
Line 52:         if ((this.DetermineSchemaSerializationMode(info, context) == global::System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema)) {
Line 53:             global::System.Data.DataSet ds = new global::System.Data.DataSet();



Stack Trace: 


[SerializationException: Member 'XmlSchema' was not found.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetElement(String name, Type& foundType) +10582902
   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetValue(String name, Type type) +64
   DataSet..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) in c:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\merchantbackoffice\4a269a66\d1e49b63\App_Code.6rrshakh.2.cs:51
   Void .ctor(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)(Object , Object[] ) +224
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.<>c__DisplayClassa.<CreateISerializableContract>b__9(Object[] args) +13
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateISerializable(JsonReader reader, JsonISerializableContract contract, String id) +271
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +606
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +91
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) +468
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) +402
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +108
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +66
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value) +42
   Account_Login1.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\abc\Desktop\testing - new\Payment\MBackOffice\Account\Login1.aspx.cs:35
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +104
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +619
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: You need to provide more information than that... I.e. what is type of `info` ...

Comment: Yeah, like what code is that?

Comment: Opps sorry, the content is updated

Comment: What are you trying to do here ?

Comment: I was trying to load my default page but it hit this error